# Why 'bridge edge loops' do not cut holes in my work?

Tags: edit-mode

I know that faces enclosed by loops disappear after 'bridge edge loops'.

[image]

But in my work, square caps still exist after bridge edge loops.

Why they didn't disappear?

In this example square caps did disappear.

[image]

Comment: I think this is because there is only one face at each end. With more faces a decision can be made to what faces are inside the loop and which are outside.

Comment: @smabler Well, I guess this is a difficult problem.